# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 - Simple Error

Tags: node.js, json

I am currently taking a course on **node.js** and I am receiving this error:
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**

The code that I anticipate is giving me this problem is:

```
    const loadNotes = function() {
       // try {
            //This code is exactly the same as the video's
            const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
            const dataJSON = JSON.toString(dataBuffer) 
            return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
        //} catch(e) {
            //return [] 
       // }
```

I checked similar answers, but they seemed more complex, and as such, I was unable to fix the problem using them.

Comment: Why do you call `JSON.toString`? What do you expect `JSON.toString(dataBuffer)` to be? Which “video” did you watch that tells you to use `JSON.toString`?

Comment: the JSON object does not have that method. You may mean `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @IvánSánchez Of course, `JSON.toString` exists. It always returns `"[object JSON]"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON.toString() is not returning what you think it is.

toString() is returning a string representation of the JSON object.

The result is: `[object JSON]`

That is not a proper JSON string so JSON.parse() fails.

So, there are two problems:

1. You are incorrectly using the prototype `toString() method`
2. You are feeding a non-JSON string to JSON.parse()

### Explanation:

Firstly, as was stated in the comments above, there is no `toString()` method defined in the JSON object. `.toString()` in the JSON object's prototype chain does do *something* when you call it but the result is a string representation of the JavaScript JSON object, not the JSON object you are attempting to read from your file. You really want to use `JSON.stringify()` instead of toString().

Here's the explanation in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString):

> Every object has a toString() method that is automatically called when
> the object is to be represented as a text value or when an object is
> referred to in a manner in which a string is expected. By default, the
> toString() method is inherited by every object descended from Object.
> If this method is not overridden in a custom object, toString()
> returns "[object type]", where type is the object type.

So, you can call `toString()` on any object in JavaScript and get `[object Object]`. But that's not what you want. So, don't use toString(). It's not doing what you think it's doing.

Secondly, be sure that you are trying to parse a **real JSON** string and not trying to parse a **JavaScript object**. There is a significant difference between the two.

Take a look at this code:

```js
let dataJS = {
  key: "value"
}
```

Above, I have defined a JavaScript object called **dataJS**.

I can convert the dataJS JavaScript object into a JSON object by using the JSON.stringify() method like this:

```js
let dataJSON = JSON.stringify(dataJS);
```

The JSON.stringify() method expects a JavaScript object and will return a JSON string. I have assigned the resulting JSON string to dataJSON. Now, I have two things: a JavaScript object called dataJS and a JSON string called dataJSON.

I can print the contents of these two things like this:

```js
console.log("JSON:\n", dataJSON)
console.log("JS:\n", dataJS)
```

Notice carefully how the two appear. You'll see this:

```
JSON:
 {"key":"value"}
JS:
 { key: 'value' }
```

Do you see the difference in between the JSON string and the JavaScript object?

The JSON string has **double-quotes** around the **key** and **value**s. The JavaScript object does not have any quotes around the **key** and single-quotes around the value.

These make JSON strings and JavaScript objects quite different.

So, if you accidentally feed the wrong thing to the JSON.parse() method you will get an error. Note what happens when I give the JSON object to the JSON.parse() method:

```js
console.log("Parse JSON:\n", JSON.parse(dataJSON))

/* result will be:
 * Parse JSON:
 *  { key: 'value' }
 */
```

That is great! The JSON.parse() method is expecting a JSON string so it works properly.

But watch what happens then I try to feed JSON.parse() the **JavaScript** object we created:

```js
console.log("Parse JS:\n", JSON.parse(dataJS))

/* result will be an ERROR:
 * undefined:1
 * [object Object]
 *  ^
 *
 * SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 
 */
```

There's your error!

So, it means that what you're feeding your JSON.parse() method in your code is **not** a JSON string.

Answer (score -2):

The "Unexpected token" error means that your JSON isn't formatted correctly. You can take a look at [this site](https://jsonlint.com/?code=) and put the contents of notes.json into it, and it will tell you whats wrong and what needs to be corrected